# Can implementing Tensorflow custom op gradients in CUDA speed computation?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

When writing your own custom op in tensorflow with GPU support, [the guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op) suggests computing the gradients using python. [Elsewhere](https://davidstutz.de/implementing-tensorflow-operations-in-c-including-gradients/) people have used C++ with libraries such as Eigen to implement the gradients in the same way, more efficiently.

My question is; with the custom operations argument Tensors provided as pointers to device memory when training on a GPU (is this correct?):

```
OpKernelContext* context
const Tensor& grad = context->input(0);
```

Can copying data between host and device be avoided by computing the gradients for the operation win CUDA on the GPU?

Will this reduce compute time? (I know this is dependant on how well the gradient computation lends itself to parallel computation, but assuming it does)

Is there any reason why this shouldn't be done?/are the potential speed increases too marginal for it to be worthwhile?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply build a op in CUDA and then call it inside the python definition of your gradient, this way you can definitely speedup gradient computation greatly and do not have to copy between GPU and CPU memory

Comment: Building an op in CUDA requires you to explicitly specify the memory locations of data to be manipulated by the GPU. In all examples this data originates on the host machine, you need to copy it to the gpu, and then manipulate it, then copy it back to the host machine in order to access it. However, if the data has been previously computed in tensorflow using CUDA, it should be possible to access data that is already on the gpu and leave it there to be accessed by future ops, thus avoiding the costly data transfer.

Comment: I do not understand why your inputs are on the host now, didn't you say they were on the GPU? You can train models fully on the GPU: forward and backward pass.